# Educating workers (micro model)

Tags: microeconomics, firm

Would someone be able to check my solutions to this basic problem? This is a practice test with no solutions provided, and I have no idea if I am going in the right direction.

Problem:
https://ibb.co/KhgwLcX

Solution (apologies my LaTex is rusty):

$\underset{c,l}{\text{max. }} c^{\alpha}l^{(1 - \alpha)}$
s.t. $c = w(24-l)$
rewritten as
$\underset{c,L}{\text{max. }} c^{\alpha}(24-L)^{(1 - \alpha)}$
s.t. $c = wL$

First order conditions:

$\alpha c^{(\alpha - 1)} = \lambda$

$(1 - \alpha)(-1)c^{\alpha}(24 - L)^{(1-\alpha)}=(-1)\lambda w$

$c = wL$

Solving this:
$L = 24\alpha$

$c = 24w\alpha$

So the labor supply is perfectly inelastic, which makes sense (you work to the extent that you value consuption over leisure).

For the markets to clear,

$b\sqrt{L} = c$

$b\sqrt{24\alpha} = 24w\alpha$

$w = \frac{b}{\sqrt{24\alpha}}$

b. Adding education in, let $\beta = \frac{L-T}{L}$, i.e. the share of labor time spent actually working. Then the firm's problem is:

$\underset{L,\beta}{\text{max. }} b\sqrt{L} - wL$ if $\beta = 1$
$\underset{L,\beta}{\text{max. }} 2a\sqrt{\beta L} - wL$ if $\beta \in [0,1)$

This is where I get a little unsure of why I'm allowed to do what I'm doing. Taking the labor supply as constant, I optimize for $\beta$ to get:

$\beta = a^2L$

Then the firm's problem becomes:

$\underset{L}{\text{max. }} 2a^2L - wL$

Here is where I get really unsure of why I'm allowed to do what I'm doing. If the derivative is constant, the firm will demand as much labor as the household will provide, which is $24\alpha$. Plugging that in, I get:

$\beta = 24a^2\alpha$

For education to be profitable, we need the extra production to be worth it, so:

$2a\sqrt{\beta L} - b\sqrt{L} < 0$
$a^2 < \frac{b}{2\sqrt{24\alpha}}$

But I also want to make sure $\beta \leq 1 $, which results in:
$a^2 \geq \frac{1}{24\alpha}$

So $a$ needs to be between $\frac{1}{24\alpha}$ and $\frac{b}{2\sqrt{24\alpha}}$

Clearing the market to find the wage:

$24wL = 2a\sqrt{24\alpha\beta}$
$w = 2a^2$

and the firm's profit is zero.

Comment: could you please make the question self contained and have not just solution but qestion as well?